# PHP: check time and output appropriate greeting

Tags: php, time

I am writing a small php program that greets according to the time of day on the server.  The rules are as follows:
Between 3:00:00 AM and 11:59:59 AM  say Good morning!.
Between 12:00:00 PM and 4:59:59 PM  say Good afternoon!.
Between 5:00:00 PM and 2:59:59 AM  say Good evening!.

First, to simply matters, I decide to use military time.  My program is as follows:

```
 function greetingWord()

                $hour = date("G");

                if($hour >= 15 && $hour < 24)
                {
                    echo "<p>Good Morning.  Today is: </p>";
                } else if($hour >= 12 && $hour < 17)
                    {
                        echo "<p>Good afternoon.  Today is: </p>";
                    }
                    else if($hour >= 17 && $hour < 3)
                    {
                        echo "<p>Good evening.  Today is: </p>";
                    }
           }
```

my question regards that last else if.  I suspect there is something wrong with my logic there so I'd apperciate it if someone would help me out with that final condition, the case of it being between 5pm and 2:59am.

Thank you!
DB

Comment: You want to change `$hour >= 17 && $hour < 3` to use or, because a number cannot be both greater than 17 and less than 3. Of course, it would never hit if the hour is greater than 15 because `if($hour >= 15 && $hour < 24)` would supersede it.

Comment: You logic is wrong. You're saying "Good morning" when hour is 23. And note you don't have to check if it's < 24 because it can't be.

Comment: Isn't 15:00 = 3:00 P.M.? I think you have that backward 03:00 = 3:00 A.M. For the morning I would think it should be($hour >= 3 && $hours < 12) for 3 A.M. to 11:59 A.M.

Comment: thank you.$hour >= 3 &&  $hour < 12 looks better.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do it is leaving the last condition with a simple "else", so:

```
function greetingWord(){
   $hour = date("G");

   if($hour > 0 && $hour < 24){
       if($hour >= 3 && $hour < 12)
        {
           echo "<p>Good Morning.  Today is: </p>";
        }else if($hour >= 12 && $hour < 17){
               echo "<p>Good afternoon.  Today is: </p>";
        }else{
           echo "<p>Good evening.  Today is: </p>";
        }
   }

}
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

I used **ternary operators** to display a part of day with a small modification of the code.

```
function greetingWord(int $hour): string
{

   return ($hour >= 3 && $hour < 12) 
          ? "Morning: " 
          : (($hour >= 12 && $hour < 17) ? "afternoon: " : "evening:");
}


foreach(range(0, 23) as $hour) {
    echo "<p> Good " . greetingWord($hour) . " Today is: ". $hour ."</p>\n";
}

//or

echo "<p> Good " . greetingWord((int) date('G')) . " Today is: ". $hour ."</p>\n";
```